# Azure windows VM extensions are provisioning failed state VM agent is "Ready" but Backup failed at VM running State GuestAgentSnapshotTaskStatusError

Tags: windows, azure

Backup is failing for Azure VM with error - GuestAgentSnapshotTaskStatusError
Azure Backup service could not communicate with the VM Agent for triggering a snapshot (to take a backup), because the VM Agent might be in an inconsistent state.
Guest Agent is in a Ready state, however, the backup extension is in a failed state. the issue is that the VM agent is ready but the VM extensions are in provisioning failed state they are as follows
1.AzureDiskEncryption
2.enablevmaccess
3.MicrosoftMonitoringAgent
4.WindowsAgent.AzureSecurityCenter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution :
You would need to re-install the Backup extension. Please follow the below **action plan:**

- Take Backup of whole Registry then use below steps :
  1.Login to the affected machine.

2. Open Registry Editor.
3. Remove VMSnapshot registry keys at **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Azure\HandlerState**
4. Remove or rename VMSnapshot Plugin Folders **at C:\Packages\Plugins**.
5. Now, open command prompt as admin and run below commands to force the extension installation :

- REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\BcdrAgent" /v IsProviderInstalled /t REG_SZ /d False /f
- REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\BcdrAgentPersistentKeys" /v IsCommonProviderInstalled /t REG_SZ /d False /f
  6.Restart the Service "WindowsAzureGuestAgent".
  7.Trigger a manual backup. As a part of backup, extension will be re-installed automatically.